# Print object name instead of memory address?

Tags: c++, oop

Let's say I have a class object named Foo() and want to return Foo's name simply by passing my print function the Foo object, not via Foo.name. For example:

```
class Object
{
public:

    Object();
    ~Object();

    const char* name;
};
```

Then

```
Debug.Log(myObject) //Should print the object name
```

What is this even called and how do I do it? At first I thought about doing an operator overload, but there's no operator to overload for this... or is there?

Comment: Can you add the `Debug.Log` function to the question?

Comment: It's just an arbitrary function. Replace with println or cout or whatever. And really? Who downvoted this and why?

Comment: The reason is that the parameter type would make a difference in which, if any, operator you could use to handle the conversion.  But hey, feel free to not add it if you don't need the help.

Comment: In your scenario I would just overload Debug's Log function to handle a parameter of type Object by accessing its name variable. The type would be Object, I thought that was apparent?

Comment: Depending on the type of the parameter you could use a conversion operator, but the type is important because different conversion operators have different drawbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different approaches are possible:

1) The usual way to do this it to [overload operator<<](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/) for each object that has to be logged, and use it on standard ostreams.

```
class Object
{
public:

    // ...

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Object& obj) {
        [...]
    }
};
```

It has many advantages, including:

- Possibility to chain th calls
- Possibility to use it with any type of stream
- STL friendly

2) If you want to stick with your design, offer a pure base class for all "Printable" object

```
class Printable{
    virtual void Print() = 0;
}
```

And have you Debug.Log function take a Printable as a parameter

```
void Log(const Printable& obj)
{
  obj.Print();
}
```

Ideally you would pass a std::ostream as a parameter of the Print() function

Comment: I did see that I could overload the << operator but I'm not sure that's the solution I'm looking for. I guess I was imagining a function that used the objects overloaded operator to print the object's name BUT I guess I could also write my own print function to handle the object and return object.name. I see that either case will work now, thanks.